# How to add a VFR map coordinate grid in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, grids-graticules

I want to add a coordinate grid like in the link below to my map. A simple grid is no problem, but I would like to know how to add the fragmentation of the lines.

[image]

Comment: By 'fragmentation' I assume you mean the tic(k)-marks along the grid lines? I'm not sure this would be possible *as* a graticule. Maybe if you could change the linetype and customize tick spacing and such. You can potentially overlay multiple graticules, but then you get them out in the middle too. It might only be possible by creating a custom vector grid layer(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the ticking mentioned by Chris W, you can use the [Station Lines Plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/stationlines/):

[image]

Note that the Station lines layers are memory layers. You have to save them to disk into another format to use them again.